# How to generate random values between 00 and FF but without having equal characters combinations?

Tags: batch-file

I would hope if it possible to have a random value between 01 and FD
but anytime you use the random command, it returns a value that don't have two time the same letters....

So, by this I would remove the value 00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF from possiblities of the random

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is unclear, you would need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56125106/edit) it to clarify and also show what you have attempted.

Comment: between `01 and FD` or between `01 and FE`?

Answer (score 2):

A naïve approach would be simply to try again if you get one of the undesirable values (pseudocode follows):

```
do
    val = random(0..255)
while val is a multiple of 17
```

Assuming you're talking about `cmd.exe`, this could be done with something like:

```
@echo off

rem Get a valid number.
:try
    set /a "xx = %random% %% 256"
    set /a "rem17 = %xx% %% 17"
    if %rem17%==0 goto :try

rem Output it as hex
echo >tmp.vbs WScript.Echo Hex(WScript.Arguments(0))
cscript /nologo tmp.vbs %xx%
del tmp.vbs
```

There are ways to do it *without* the possibility of having to try multiple times (with a bit of setup beforehand) but, given you're using `cmd`, I suspect performance isn't a massive concern :-)

Comment: To exclude `00` and `17*15 = FF` from start, it is a tad more efficient to use ***one*** command `set /a "xx=%random% %% 254 +1,rem17=xx %% 17"` (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple formula to avoid the multiples of 17 (and avoid looping at all).
The trick is to divide by 16 (not 17), because each *serie* has only 16 consecutive values.

```
@echo off

set /a val=1 + ( %random% %% 240 )    
set /a sane=(val - 1) / 16 + val    
call :dec2hex %sane%
echo %hex%
exit /b

:dec2hex
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a nibbleHigh=%1 / 16
set /a nibbleLow=%1 %% 16
set "hexMap=0123456789ABCDEF"
set "hex=!hexMap:~%nibbleHigh%,1!!hexMap:~%nibbleLow%,1!"
(
  endlocal
  set "hex=%hex%"
  exit /b
)
```

Answer (score 2):

same math as in paxdiablo's answer, but convert to hex in pure `cmd` (without `vbs`):

```
:loop
set /a val=%random% %% 256
set /a chk=val %% 17
if %chk%==0 goto :loop
call cmd /c exit /b %val%
echo %=exitcode:~-2%
goto :loop
```

Comment: With the echo replaced by `set /P _=%=exitcode:~-2% <NUL` it fills the screen; not just like matrix... ;-)

Comment: @LotPings: but just a "tiny little bit" slower than in the Matrix films ... `:D`